# Recursive in java

Tags: recursion

```
public static void mystery(int num)  {

   System.out.print(num % 100);
   if ((num / 100) != 0) 
      mystery(num / 100);
  System.out.print(num % 100);
}
```

When I call mystery(456789), the result is 896745456789.
Why does it not stop at 89674545?

Comment: It is because of the last print line

Answer (score 0):

Let see for the first call. `num % 100` is 89.

Your code:

```
print 89
.. do what ever
print 89
```

So it will print `89...whatever...89`

It doesn't stop at `45` because it only return from the 3rd call, doesn't affect the first call.

Answer (score 0):

As I guessed you wanted to reverse integer two by two digits. Well, method and logic isn't wrong but there is additional line. When number is devidedd by 100 and then it's given to recursion function, **System.out.print(num % 100)** is automatically done in that recursion, so printing it after recursion again causes additional numbers in answer.

```
public class Recursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mystery(456789);
    }

    public static void mystery(int num)  {

        System.out.print(num % 100);
        if ((num / 100) != 0)
            mystery(num / 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output as you specified in your question try the below code

```
public static void mystery(int num)  {

   System.out.print(num % 100);
   if ((num / 100) != 0) 
   {
      mystery(num / 100);
   }
  else
  {
      System.out.print(num);
  }
}
```

Input: mystery(456789);
Output: 89674545